Can a Judge increase a sentence if previous leniency was abused?
If a Judge is sentencing a repeat offender who was previously shown leniency for a similar offence,  can the Judge increase the current sentence to reflect that leniency didn't have any effect the first time?
As an example - let's say a Judge is sentencing a burglar for a crime that would typically warrant a 6 month custodial sentence. His lawyer makes a convincing case for leniency (first offence, comes from a broken home, lead astray by others, fallen on hard times, sick mother to support etc etc). The Judge decides to give the offender a 2nd chance and gives a non-custodial sentence.
12 months later the offender is back in court for a similar offence that (as before) would normally warrant a 6 month sentence. Would the Judge be allowed increase the current sentence to say 12 months if he feels that leniency obviously didn't work and the offender just lied himself out of prison the 1st time with a convincing sob story? Or is the Judge required to consider the current case only?

Not as such: the existing sentence stands on its own and can't be revised (other than in limited circumstances by an appeal court). However leniency might well have been shown in the first case by a suspended sentence. If the offender then comes back within the term of suspension then the original sentence gets added to whatever is given to punish the second offence.

I understand the first sentence has to stand, but is the Judge allowed to be extra-harsh with the 2nd sentence if he feels the offender was taking-the-piss the first time round?

@ConanTheGerbil, up to a point yes. The judge cannot impose a harder sentence than the maximum that the law proscribes for the offense, but they can take the past behavior of the defendant into account both in the direction of leniency and in the direction of a harder sentence.

Kinda in germany
Assume Bob was convicted of theft for 1 year, which was suspended for parole under  §§ 56ff StGB. In turn, now Bob needs to behave well for between 2 and 5 years and stay without any conviction or go to prison for the whole term of his punishment.
Now, let's say Bob was arrested for theft again, and once more gets convicted. Now he is not an "Ersttäter" (first-time offender) but he is "vorbestraft" (convicted offender). This in itself shifts the onus on the defense: not only does Bob (in theory) have to go to jail for the year from his first conviction, but he also might get the non-reduced punishment. The worse his behavior, the more time can be accrued - up to 5 years for the theft, as that is the maximum permitted by law for a theft.

england-and-wales
It depends.
A "relevant" previous conviction must be treated as an aggravating factor for the purpose of sentencing. But there are some caveats/qualifications.
Sentencing Council guidance on previous convictions:


Previous convictions are considered at step two in the Council’s offence-specific guidelines.
The primary significance of previous convictions (including convictions in other jurisdictions) is the extent to which they
indicate trends in offending behaviour and possibly the offender’s
response to earlier sentences.
Previous convictions are normally of relevance to the current offence when they are of a similar type.
Previous convictions of a type different from the current offence may be of relevance where they are an indication of persistent
offending or escalation and/or a failure to comply with previous court
orders.
Numerous and frequent previous convictions might indicate an underlying problem (for example, an addiction) that could be addressed
more effectively in the community and will not necessarily indicate
that a custodial sentence is necessary.
If the offender received a non-custodial disposal for the previous offence, a court should not necessarily move to a custodial sentence
for the fresh offence.
In cases involving significant persistent offending, the community and custody thresholds may be crossed even though the current offence
normally warrants a lesser sentence. If a custodial sentence is
imposed it should be proportionate and kept to the necessary minimum.
The aggravating effect of relevant previous convictions reduces with the passage of time; older convictions are of less relevance to
the offender’s culpability for the current offence and less likely to
be predictive of future offending.
Where the previous offence is particularly old it will normally have little relevance for the current sentencing exercise.
The court should consider the time gap since the previous conviction and the reason for it. Where there has been a significant
gap between previous and current convictions or a reduction in the
frequency of offending this may indicate that the offender has made
attempts to desist from offending in which case the aggravating effect
of the previous offending will diminish.
Where the current offence is significantly less serious than the previous conviction (suggesting a decline in the gravity of
offending), the previous conviction may carry less weight.
When considering the totality of previous offending a court should take a rounded view of the previous crimes and not simply aggregate
the individual offences.
Where information is available on the context of previous offending this may assist the court in assessing the relevance of that
prior offending to the current offence


Section 65 Sentencing Act 2020:

Previous convictions:
(1) This section applies where a court is considering the seriousness of an offence (“the current offence”) committed by an offender who has one or more relevant previous convictions.
(2) The court must treat as an aggravating factor each relevant previous conviction that it considers can reasonably be so treated, having regard in particular to—
(a) the nature of the offence to which the relevant previous conviction relates and its relevance to the current offence, and
(b) the time that has elapsed since the relevant previous conviction. ...


(7) For the purposes of this section, an offence is “relevant” if the offence would constitute an offence under the law of any part of the United Kingdom if it were done in that part at the time of the conviction of the offender for the current offence.


canada
The previous criminal record cannot be used for its own sake to increase a sentence for a later offence. But it may reveal other aspects of the offender's character that can be considered during sentencing.
R. v. Sinclair, 2022 MBCA 65 at para. 43:

An individual’s criminal record cannot be used to increase sentence since that would be to punish the accused twice.  However, it can be used to assess future behaviour and to assess the accused’s prospects for rehabilitation and his ongoing risk to reoffend.  Consideration of a prior criminal record can assist a judge in determining the normative character of that accused.  When that record shows repeated related criminal behaviour, it may be viewed as an aggravating factor (thereby causing the sentence to be increased within the appropriate range of sentences) in order to address specific deterrence, protection of society and/or the prospects of rehabilitation.

